# NER activation function in SPACY

Tags: spacy, named-entity-recognition, softmax, relu

I have searched the documentation, but I couldn't find the answer. Does SPACY uses ReLu, Softmax or both as activation function?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

By default, SPACY uses both, as we can see in layers architectures page from SPACY 3.0:

https://spacy.io/usage/layers-architectures